# Replace Only if it Has Exact Number of Occurence in RegEx Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have another Regular Expression problem and seems what was stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) doesn't work, probably I am missing something. Here's my code snippet

```js
var uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:7777/users/56e8203d';
var replaceUri = uri.replace(/\/(\w+){8}$/, '');

console.log(replaceUri);
```

What I am planning to do here is to replace the matched alpha numeric chars if it meets the number of occurrence. I think I was wrongly applied x{n} regex algo.

It means it will only replace if it detects the ID, which is 8 chars.

Thank you!

Comment: `(\w+){8}` makes little sense as you are matching 1 or more alphanumerics 8 times. I guess you were after `uri.replace(/\/\w{8}$/, '');`

Comment: @stribizhev  is absolutely right.  Your regex is a bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `/\/(\w+){8}$/` has an issue: nested quantifiers. You are matching 1 or more alphanumerics (`\w+`) 8 times (`{8}`). Note that the quantifier is applied to the adjoining construct on the left: a single character, a character class, a shorthand character class, or a grouping. (Note that you cannot place a quantifier on lookarounds or start of string).

To only match 8 alphanumerics at the end of the string after `/`, use

```
\/\w{8}$
```

See the demo below:

```js
var uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:7777/users/56e8203d';
var replaceUri = uri.replace(/\/\w{8}$/, '');
console.log(replaceUri);
```

Comment: Note that to match 8 alphanumeric characters at the end of the string and only if there are 8, not 9, you can use a word boundary: `\b\w{8}$`.

Comment: Hi stribizhev! This would be a great help! I used your code snippet above, I remove the quantifier and + . :D